# NET 6 WebAPI - column mapping. How to do it fast and automaticaly?

Tags: orm, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm looking for a solution to do a column mapping. The database is not mine, and I am just making some kind of additional software for an existing database where column naming is terrible. I want to handle full CRUD, but now I'm using `DapperExtensions.Mapper`, which is mapping only for update/insert, but data selection with `QueryAsync` is not mapped. I am getting zeros and nulls. I need to add `[MyPropertyName]` in the select query.

There are a lot of tables that contain a lot of columns:

1. Documents table has 262 columns
2. Payments have two tables, first with 90 columns, second with 87
3. Customers - 171 columns

Is there any way to map those faster? A solution that works both ways add/edit and select with one configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use `EF Core Db First` to map column and handle CRUD.

> **Reverse Engineering:**
>
> Reverse engineering is the process of scaffolding entity type classes
> and a DbContext class based on a database schema. It can be performed
> using the `Scaffold-DbContex`t command of the EF Core Package Manager
> Console (PMC) tools or the `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` command of
> the .NET Command-line Interface (CLI) tools.

More details your can refer to [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli),[link2](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: Yes... That's what I thought. But what if I need some kind of additional column that needs data from other tables? For example `Document.PaymentStatus` can be `settled`, `partially settled` or `not settled` and that information is in `Payments` table.

Comment: If the table has relationship, After Reverse Engineering, The model will have relationship. All the relationship between generated models depends on the original database.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware how it works, but the logic behind `PaymentStatus` is more complex than just use like `Document.Payments.Status`. It is not just one column/property, it is a whole new, additional `select` statement if you do it with normal SQL query. That is why I used Dapper for so long, but now I need to add/edit data also and it is painfulll with Dapper...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Dapper, but if you use EF core, I think you can use linq to simulate sql statements which you need.